# Sqlalchemy query: select using list of tuples

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

So I have a list of tuples like `[('Alex', 20), ('Steve', 50)]`

Now I need to fire a select query on Users table to get matching records.

I tried it like:-

```
users = [('Alex', 20), ('Steve', 50)]
names = [r[0] for r in users]
ages = [r[1] for r in users]

query = self.session.query(Users).filter(
                      and_(Users.name.in_(names),
                      Users.age.in_(ages)))
```

I want the records with `Alex` user of age `20` and `Steve` user of age `50`, but this query would also give me `Alex` user of age `50`.

So this query doesn't really work out. Need some help figuring out this query.

Comment: The query is fine - you need to explain what you expect and what's wrong. Could it be you actually want `Alex` users of age `20` and `Steve` users of age `50`?

Comment: Yes right. Because this query will also give me `Alex` user of age `50`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get only users whose name and age matches your `users` list you'll have to combine the `name` and `age` filters with `AND` clauses and join these in an `OR` clause.
E.g. like this:

```
user_filters = [and_(Users.name == name, Users.age == age)
                for name, age in users]
self.session.query(Users).filter(or_(*user_filters))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thankyou...But `or` seems not to be needed. Is that really required?

Comment: It is needed - `filter(*user_filters)` would join all those filters with `AND`, which would most probably result in an empty results because something like `users.name = "Alex" AND users.name = "Steve"` can't be true.